# How to group data to minimize the variance while preserving the order of the data in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame (760 rows)  with two columns, named Price and Size. I would like to put the data into 4/5 groups based on price that would minimize the variance in each group while preserving the order Size (which is in ascending order). The Jenks natural breaks optimization would be an ideal function however it does not take the order of Size into consideration.

Basically, I have data simlar to the following (with more data)

```
Price=c(90,100,125,100,130,182,125,250,300,95)

Size=c(10,10,10.5,11,11,11,12,12,12,12.5)  

mydata=data.frame(Size,Price)
```

I would like to group data, to minimize the variance of price in each group respecting 1) The Size value: For example, the first two prices 90 and 100 cannot be in a different groups since they are the same size & 2) The order of the Size: For example, If Group One includes observations (Obs) 1-2 and Group Two includes observations  3-9, observation 10 can only enter into group two or three.

Can someone please give me some advice? Maybe there is already some such function that I can’t find?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? With the `dplyr` package, grouping is quite easy. The `%>%`can be read as "then do" so you can combine multiple actions if you like.

See http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html for further information.

```
library("dplyr")
Price <– c(90,100,125,100,130,182,125,250,300,95)
Size <- c(10,10,10.5,11,11,11,12,12,12,12.5)  

mydata <- data.frame(Size,Price) %>% # "then"
  group_by(Size) # group data by Size column

mydata_mean_sd <- mydata %>%  # "then"
  summarise(mean = mean(Price), sd = sd(Price)) # calculate grouped
                                         #mean and sd for illustration
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer Konn. However, this groups data just with similar size, I would like to allow different sizes to be grouped, respecting the order of size. ie all prices with the same size must be in the same group. I'm trying to group data that minimizes the price variance in each group respecting the points 1) and 2) as stated in the question. Any Advice?

Comment: You are right. The answer above is useful for working with groups you already have. Maybe the `cut()` function from base R helps you separate groups . [Here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-function-of-the-day-cut/) is an example for using `cut()` inside a custom function. Maybe someone else can help with the function itself.

Comment: Thanks for the link Konn. Can anyone else please help with this??

Comment: I've got a similar task to work on - have you got any progress on this @Newbie? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with optimally splitting a day into 4 "load blocks". Adjacent time periods must stick together, of course.

Not an elegant solution, but I wrote my own function that first split up a sorted series at specified break points, then calculates the sum(SDCM) using those break points (using the algorithm underlying the jenks approach from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenks_natural_breaks_optimization#Description_of_Method)).

Then just iterated through all valid combinations of break points, and selected the set of points that produced the minimum sum(SDCM).

Would quickly become unmanageable as number of possible breakpoints combinations increases, but it worked for my data set.